# How to give the path to file browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to develop a file browser in which user can access the files in a specific folder.So i have to give the starting path to this file browser.But it's generating exception that not a virtual path. How can i resolve this ? 
Here is my code :

```
string startingDir =Server.MapPath(@"d:/abc");
            lblCurrentDir.Text = startingDir;
            ShowFilesIn(startingDir);
            ShowDirectoriesIn(startingDir);
```

Comment: Why not just use the file upload control?

Comment: Server.MapPath() is a function that Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path. So the argument you specify here should be a location/path located at the server file system.

Comment: I have the folder in d drive named reports and i want to give the path of this folder how can i do this ? as i am developing this i am on local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was , i was trying to access the path of the folder which is outside my project folder so i copy the desired folder in my project folder and modified the path as :

```
string startingDir =Server.MapPath(@"Reports\");
            lblCurrentDir.Text = startingDir;
            ShowFilesIn(startingDir);
            ShowDirectoriesIn(startingDir);
```